# <span> + <sup> having a white-space inbetween caused by a line-break

Tags: html

The following HTML snippet is rendered with a whitespace between the two words (with a line-break between both lines:

```
<span>foo</span>
<sup>bar</sup>
```

However

```
<span>foo</span><sup>bar</sup>
```

is rendered without a whitespace between both words.

So why does the line-break cause this behavior. Line-break or not should not influence the rendering here!?

Comment: Not just the line-break. Any white-space character does that...

Comment: Might be useful: [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are treated as white space, so one or more line-breaks are treated as a single whitespace (just like all the other white space characters)

> A line break is defined to be a carriage return (`&#x000D;`), a line
>   feed (`&#x000A;`), or a carriage return/line feed pair. All line breaks
>   constitute white space.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#line-breaks

Comment: I believe [this](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/) is the preferred HTML standard now.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a line break is equivalent to a space in HTML. There are some exceptions, and according to [formal rules on line breaks](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/notes.html#h-B.3.1), the break *should* be ignored on two accounts (it immediately follows a start tag *and* immediately precedes an end tag). But browsers never implemented such features properly, so they treat your markup as equivalent to

```
<span>foo</span> <sup>bar</sup>
```

The conclusion is that you should write an end tag and a start tag on the same line, if you wish to have no space in content between the elements.

You can have line breaks inside tags, though, e.g.

```
<span>foo</span><sup
class=zap>bar</sup>
```

Answer (score -1):

For CJK (Chinese Japanese Korean) characters, it might be hard to find the break point, it is possible to insert booststrap's `<span class="sr-only"></span>` as the way to break the line for better code reading, example:

```
这是一<span class="sr-only">
</span>行无空格的文字
```