# Html css justify glitch with angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, css, justify

I am trying to make a element with inner elements that should be justified.

Now is the problem that when I generate the elements with AngularJS text-align justify does not works anymore.

I've made a example that simulate it:

http://jsfiddle.net/2AaWf/1/

```
.container {
   text-align: justify;
}
span, a {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Is there anything I can change in AngularJS or with CSS.

How can i do this ?

AngularJS code:

```
<a ng-repeat="tag in tags" href="#">{{tag.name}}</a>
```

tags is just a javascript array:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Tag name","count":"1","weight":2}]
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular. It's pure CSS. How do you generate your HTML with angular ? You can definitely generate it to look like your first example.

Comment: Show the relevant  angular code

Comment: is this what you need?

Comment: Inline block elements won't justify like that. Inline elements will. I think all you need beyond that are some spaces in between your elements.

Answer (score 1):

### Analysis

I was stumped when I first saw this, but after some digging, I found out why. This question is somewhat related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928194/span-sup-having-a-white-space-inbetween-caused-by-a-line-break). Just to quote:

> In general, a line break is equivalent to a space in HTML. There are some exceptions, and according to formal rules on line breaks, the break should be ignored on two accounts (it immediately follows a start tag and immediately precedes an end tag). **But browsers never implemented such features properly, so they treat your markup as equivalent to ...**

What is going on here, is that in your second example, each item is placed next to the next item *without* any white space. Without any white space, the browser treats it as a continuous word.

```
He<b>llo, Wo</b>rld!
```

Is rendered inline:

```
Hello, World
```

In your case, the following code:

```
<a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
```

Is rendered inline as

```
Lorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsumLorem ipsum
```

So it treats the whole thing as one inline *box*.

### Solution

Below is a solution, but I'm not sure why it works. Essentially, you want to wrap your anchors and force a white space character into your template. The interesting thing is that if you replace the `<b>` with a `<span>`, the whole thing breaks again. This makes no sense to me as both `<b>` and `<span>` are inline elements. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2AaWf/11/)

If someone with more in-depth knowledge on why `<b>` and `<span>` makes a difference, please let me know. I tried messing around with the css for `<span>`, but the results are always the same.

Angular Template:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" class="container">
    <b ng-repeat="tag in tags">
        <a href="#">{{tag.name}}</a>
    </b>
    <span class="last-child"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
}

.container b {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.container a, .container span {
    display: inline-block;
}

.last-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```