# Reduce white space between two consecutive <sup> elements

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```html
<p>Test
  <sup>1</sup>
  <sup>, 2</sup>
</p>
```

Which are displayed like `1 , 2`. When I try apply some style I don't know where, since no margins or paddings are set. So, which style should I apply for all but the first `sup`?

Comment: Alternative idea: just use one `sup`

Comment: One element cannot be used since I need to store more information in it. I need to have two different elements.

Comment: `One element cannot be used since I need to store more information in it` This doesn't make any sense. If you need links you can do `<sup><a>1</a>,<a>2</a></sup>`. You're trying to solve your problem the hard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try just using one `sup`. If you need two, you can also try applying a negative `margin` on `sup`. Since you don't need it on the `first-child` but need it on all other children, use this:

```css
p > sup:not(:first-child) {}
```

See it working here:

```css
p>sup:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: -4px;
}
```

```html
<p>Test
  <sup>1,2,</sup>
  <sup>3</sup>
</p>

<p>Test
  <sup>1,</sup>
  <sup>2,</sup>
  <sup>3,</sup>
  <sup>4</sup>
</p>

<p>Test
  <sup>1,</sup>
  <sup>2,</sup>
  <sup>3,</sup>
  <sup>4,</sup>
  <sup>5,</sup>
  <sup>6,</sup>
  <sup>7,</sup>
  <sup>8</sup>
</p>
```

Comment: I like approach the most. But some concerns: it won't apply to the first `p` Therefore I think the more appropriate version should be `p > sup:nth-child(2)`. Which is OK as long as I won't have more than 2 (i.e. n-elements). So how to apply if for `not(first)`? Because `p > sup:not(first-child)` applies it as well to the first (which I don't understand why?)

Comment: @LeO I only used `p:nth-child(2)` for demonstration purposes. Also, you need to add `:` in the `:not(:first-child)`. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/jm2kutox/2/), works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve your problem ?

```
<p>
    <sup>1, 2</sup>
</p>
```

If you have to use two  elements, then try

```
<p>test
      <sup>1</sup>
      <sup style="margin:0; margin-left:-5; padding:0;">, 2</sup>
</p>
```

I hope I could help you, otherwise I'll need some more info.

Comment: I need to place it within a `style` in a CSS. I cannot apply it directly on the element. I didn't think about the `margin-left` option. At least this is some kind of idea I need to check further.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928194/span-sup-having-a-white-space-inbetween-caused-by-a-line-break

Comment: I think it will be fine if you add it in your css file, if you want to be sure that it will not affect other elements you can add an id attribute to your sup element and put the css rule using the id selector. I can edit my answer if my comment isn't clear

Answer (score 1):

Just place the comma inside the first `<sup>` element rather than in the subsequent ones like so:

```html
<p>Test
  <sup>1,</sup>
  <sup> 2</sup>
</p>
```

Comment: Even more simple  haven't thought about that kind of approach. I like this one very much.